# How to add items to a stringArray in an arrayList programmatically?

Tags: android, arrays

This is my *array.xml* file in the *res/values* folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="updateInterval">
           <item name="1000">Pico TTS</item>
          <item name="5000">Invox TTs</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I need to add some more items to the `updateInterval` array list. How can I add the items that are dynamically coming from server programmatically?

Comment: ...and one more thought. Consider maintaining a SQLite DB with new data coming from the server instead of a string array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't add item directly to that string array.

But you can use that array and dynamically add elements to that string array.

Do in this way.

```
    String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.updateInterval);
    System.out.println("--array.length--"+array.length);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list = Arrays.asList(array);
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(list);
    arrayList.add("TTS");
    array = arrayList.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    System.out.println("--array.length--"+array.length);
```

Comment: how does this add an item to "undateInterval" ?

Comment: He is showing you to create a new array based on the old one, then you can add things to it via the ArrayList and Array types.

Comment: so how would you then save this back to sharedpreferences?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to edit an xml resource dynamically, you just can have an static arraylist in case you need some data at runtime plus xml data.