# Programmatically change array stored in resources

Tags: android, arrays, xml, spinner

I have a toolbar. And spinner that set on it. Now this spinner is strongly integrated in my code. So I prefer not change the structure mentioned down. Now the problem is that I have to store array in the resources. This is the problem because I want to programatically add/(delete) items that stored there. So the question is: If it is possible to prepare this array in activity?(and store ready array into resources) Or if is possible to add/delete specific item to array that locate into resources?

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.category, R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
            Spinner navigationSpinner = new Spinner(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
            navigationSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
            toolbar.addView(navigationSpinner, 0);
```

This is how array looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="category">
        <item>All lists</item>
        <item>Default</item>
        <item>Finished</item>
        <item>New List</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I found part of answer. But this allows only getting data from there, and not to store it after the treatment.
[How to add items to a stringArray in an arrayList programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799572/how-to-add-items-to-a-stringarray-in-an-arraylist-programmatically)

Comment: You can modify the in-memory array. But you can't save it in your resources.

Comment: "modify the in-memory array" what do you mean?

Comment: You will read the array into an object, right? OK, you can copy that and add or remove items to THAT one. But you can't save the updates to a file in the resources folder. The resources folder is untouchable.

Comment: `ArrayAdapter.createFromResource` calls a method, what creates an in-memory array ([see line 391](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java), or line 204 [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/content/res/AssetManager.java))

Comment: It means rewrite... Thanks